# How to use jQuery to validate North American phone number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to validate phone numbers like (123) 456-7890 or 1234567890
 How should be the 'matches' condition be written in the following code?

```
form.validate({

    rules: {

       phoneNumber: {matches:"[0-9]+",minlength:10, maxlength:10}
```

Comment: What is `matches` supposed to be?  There is no such method in this plugin.

Comment: The code is customized

Comment: Then you should have mentioned that in the OP.  Why not use one of the several [phone number rules already provided by this plugin](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js)?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your regex should be something like

`[0-9\-\(\)\s]+`.

It matches numbers, dashes, parentheses and space.

If you need something more strict, matching just your example, try this:

`([0-9]{10})|(\([0-9]{3}\)\s+[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4})`

Comment: Are you sure the first  expression is correct? I tried but did not work for me.

Comment: @KarueBensonKarue `var phone_pattern = /([0-9]{10})|(\([0-9]{3}\)\s+[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4})/; phone_pattern.test( input_value );`

Comment: This is perfect

Answer (score 28):

Your code:

```
rules: {
    phoneNumber: {
        matches: "[0-9]+",  // <-- no such method called "matches"!
        minlength:10,
        maxlength:10
    }
}
```

**There is no such callback function, option, method, or rule called `matches` anywhere within [the jQuery Validate plugin](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js).**  (*EDIT:  OP failed to mention that `matches` is his custom method.*)

However, within [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js), there are several phone number validation methods you can use.  The one called `phoneUS` should satisfy your pattern.  Since the rule already validates the length, `minlength` and `maxlength` are redundantly unnecessary.  It's also much more comprehensive in that area codes and prefixes can not start with a `1`.

```
rules: {
    phoneNumber: {
        phoneUS: true
    }
}
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/eWhkv/**

---

If, for whatever reason, you just need the regex for use in another method, you can take it from here...

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function(phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, "");
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 && 
    phone_number.match(/^(\+?1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
}, "Please specify a valid phone number");
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have to main the code standard. They do stuffs the way I wrote. And I am a newbie in jquery :'(

Comment: @Mr.Flint, like I showed in the last part of my answer, there is a very good phone number regex within that method you can take and use instead... isn't that what you asked for?  It really makes no sense to write code for something that already exists... especially if you're a newbie.

Comment: @Mr.Flint, and if you had shown the `matches` method in your OP, we could have created a working demo for you.

Comment: @Sparky Thanks lot for save me time.

Answer (score 22):

```
function validatePhone(txtPhone) {
    var a = document.getElementById(txtPhone).value;
    var filter = /^((\+[1-9]{1,4}[ \-]*)|(\([0-9]{2,3}\)[ \-]*)|([0-9]{2,4})[ \-]*)*?[0-9]{3,4}?[ \-]*[0-9]{3,4}?$/;
    if (filter.test(a)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Demo**  http://jsfiddle.net/dishantd/JLJMW/496/

Comment: This has nothing to do with the validate plugin.

Answer (score 17):

```
/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/
```

Supports :

- (123) 456 7899
- (123).456.7899
- (123)-456-7899
- 123-456-7899
- 123 456 7899
- 1234567899

Comment: hmm ... how about this one :/^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/

Answer (score 5):

If you normalize your data first, then you can avoid all the very complex regular expressions required to validate phone numbers. From my experience, complicated regex patterns can have two unwanted side effects: (1) they can have unexpected behavior that would be a pain to debug later, and (2) they can be slower than simpler regex patterns, which may become noticeable when you are executing regex in a loop.

By keeping your regular expressions as simple as possible, you reduce these risks and your code will be easier for others to follow, partly because it will be more predictable. To use your phone number example, first we can normalize the value by stripping out all non-digits like this:

`value = $.trim(value).replace(/\D/g, '');`

Now your regex pattern for a US phone number (or any other locale) can be much simpler:

`/^1?\d{10}$/`

Not only is the regular expression much simpler, it is also easier to follow what's going on: a value optionally leading with number one (US country code) followed by ten digits. If you want to format the validated value to make it look pretty, then you can use this slightly longer regex pattern:

`/^1?(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/`

This means an optional leading number one followed by three digits, another three digits, and ending with four digits. With each group of numbers memorized, you can output it any way you want. Here's a codepen using jQuery Validation to illustrate this for two locales (Singapore and US):

http://codepen.io/thdoan/pen/MaMqvZ

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery.validator.methods.matches = function( value, element, params ) {
    var re = new RegExp(params);
    // window.console.log(re);
    // window.console.log(value);
    // window.console.log(re.test( value ));
    return this.optional( element ) || re.test( value );
}

rules: {
        input_telf: {
            required  : true,
            matches   : "^(\\d|\\s)+$",
            minlength : 10,
            maxlength : 20
        }
    }
```

Comment: how is this used in the context of the .validate() method?

Comment: It's used in the rules section, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I thought I would share my solution to help others.

This function will work if you want to valid 10 digits phone number "US number"

```
function getValidNumber(value)
{
    value = $.trim(value).replace(/\D/g, '');

    if (value.substring(0, 1) == '1') {
        value = value.substring(1);
    }

    if (value.length == 10) {

        return value;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Here how to use this method

```
var num = getValidNumber('(123) 456-7890');
if(num !== false){
     alert('The valid number is: ' + num);
} else {
     alert('The number you passed is not a valid US phone number');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is work for me:-

```
/^\(?(\d{3})\)?[-\. ]?(\d{3})[-\. ]?(\d{4})$/
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the below solution and it work fine for me.

```
/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/
```

Tried below phone format:

- +(123) 456 7899
- (123) 456 7899
- (123).456.7899
- (123)-456-7899
- 123-456-7899
- 123 456 7899
- 1234567899

Comment: your regexp not check if phone number is 111 in input, how i can check this, if example user type only 111 or 123?