# asp.net C# get textbox lenght from backend

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, model-view-controller

I would like to inform user if he is adding more character than he needs for a certain field.

my code behind :

```
if (txt1.txt.??? < X)
{
   alert(You exceed to the max amount of characters, max is X number);
}
```

Comment: Validators have you heard or tried them?

Comment: try `if (txt1.Text.Length < 11)`

Comment: Really? That's your code behind? I doubt it, that doesn't even come close to being compilable. Have you actually tried anything? Generally, questions that are actually just requirements with no real effort shown and just asking for a solution are too broad or otherwise off-topic for SO.

Comment: By the way, what if someone enters their phone number in the format of `(XXX) XXX-XXX` or `XXX-XXX-XXXX` or `XX-XXX-XXX-XXXX`? You should use built in validators which are capable of recognizing valid phone number formats.

Comment: I recommend you do this with JavaScript/Jquery or like everyone else is saying, a AJAX Toolkit validator, but those are gross. Look at it from a users point of view, do you want the page to postback just to find out your phone number is not correct? This post will get you started on a JQuery phone number validator http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840301/jquery-to-validate-phone-number

Comment: @snowYetis Nobody said to use the validator from the AJAX Control Toolkit, we just said use a validator. And it's often necessary to validate things on the client **and** server side, because you can't always trust data from the client.

Comment: @mason you make a good point. There is a chance of a user changing client side code from source before submitting to server. Isn't the asp:RegularExpressionValidator from the AJAX Toolkit? It has been a while since I touched or looked at any ASP.Net Webform code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the length of a textbox value from behind code.

```
if(txt1.Text.Length < 11)
{
 //Your code here
}
else
{
  //Your Code here 
}
```

However, why don't you used a textbox masked extender like Ajax or a RegularExpressionValidator validation?

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter valid Phone number" ControlToValidate="txt1" ValidationExpression="\d{10}" ValidChars="()-" ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```