# validate iput in jquery in specific code structure

Tags: jquery, validation

Hello i'm at coding my form and i have validate it with jquery and php but i need that in my phone input only digit to be usable and a min of 6 numbers must appear . in this jquery code structure :

```
   if ($('input[name="phone"]' ).val().length ===0){
       erros = 1;
    }
    else {
      $('input[name="phone"]').removeClass('warning');
    }
```

here the phone input code :

```
<label class="label">Phone Number</label>
                            <label class="input">
                                <i class="icon-append fa fa-phone"></i>
                                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" >
                            </label>
```

How to base the jquery validation on my needs ? thanks in advance

I just updated my script and i made it somehow to validate only digit input but now i cant go foward until 10 numbers are typet on the phone input box here the code :

```
  var phoneVal=$('input[name="phone"]').val();
   phoneantigo = phoneVal.toString();
     var phoneReg = /\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})$/;

     if ($('input[name="phone"]').val().length === 0) {

       erros = 1;}
       else if(!phoneReg.test(phoneVal)) {

      $('input[name="phone"]').val('');
            erros = 1;

        }
     else {
       $('input[name="phone"]').removeClass('warning');}//end of test
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840301/jquery-to-validate-phone-number

Comment: i'm checking that right now thanks @Daniel

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#phone').on('input', function (event) { 
    $this.val() = $this.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); // allow only numeric characters
    if ($this.length < 6){ // if less than 6 characters, add warning class
       erros = 1;
       $this.addClass('warning');
    } else {
      $this.removeClass('warning');
    }
});
```

Comment: I haven't downvoted this answer but I alsways feel a bit of explanation does good to a piece of code.

Comment: You did down vote... and if you know how to read, I think you can figure it out @Trilarion.