# Check textbox on specific format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an issue.. I want to check a textbox for a specific format.

I will explain it with an example:

When the user types someting in a textbox. For example a phone number such as: 06-12345678

If the user types the phone number correct, a popup comes up with a message such as: You've entered the phone number correctly.

If the user types it incorrectly, a popup comes up with a message such as: You've entered the phone number incorrectly.

I've already made a jsfiddle for the textboxes, but not for the phone number check.

```
<input type="text" id="correct" value="06-12345678"><br><br>
<input type="text" id="wrong" value="06 12345678">
```

Jsfiddle link: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1Lswskg/2/)

I hope you can help me out

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840301/jquery-to-validate-phone-number

Comment: use jQuery validation to customize your own rules in this case

Comment: You have not defined the format for phone numbers; “such as...” is not a format definition. Once you have defined it, write it as a regular expresion; the rest is elementary HTML5 (`pattern` attribute) and/or JavaScript. In the definition, it is crucial how you define the format, including permitted or required punctuation. There is a large variety of practices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the change event.

```js
function checkNumber(box) {
  if (box.value.match("^[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{8}$") !== null) {
    alert("You entered the phone number correctly");
  }
  else {
    alert("You entered the phone number incorrectly");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onchange="checkNumber(this)" value="" placeholder="Phone Number" />
```

Comment: May I ask you what you've changed and what it does?

Comment: I add a `^` to the beginning, and a `$` to the end, which says that it must match the full thing. Just the `^` would mean that it would need to start at the beginning, and just `$` would mean it would have to be found at the end, both means that we're matching the entire string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pattern` attribute in HTML 5.

Example:

```html
    <input type="text" pattern="^((\+\d{1,3}(-| )?\(?\d\)?(-| )?\d{1,5})|(\(?\d{2,6}\)?))(-| )?(\d{3,4})(-| )?(\d{4})(( x| ext)\d{1,5}){0,1}$">
```