# Validate phone in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this input field that the user need to put his phone number:

```
<input type="text" id="Phone" />
```

I want to validate if the number is in the correct format.
The format should be this:
Only 10 digits (no letters, no "-" and no other characters)
Can someone help me please?

Comment: You need to user regex which will check the pattern of your phone Num, You can use this : ^[0-9\-\+]{9,15}$

Comment: When you did a Google search for "JavaScript validate phone number", it didn't find *anything at all*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery to validate phone number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840301/jquery-to-validate-phone-number)

Comment: @devlincarnate Current Question does not appear to be a duplicate of the linked Question ? Expected input at present Question is _"Only 10 digits (no letters, no "-" and no other characters)"_ ?

Comment: @HussamEddin _"The format should be this: Only 10 digits (no letters, no "-" and no other characters)"_ Does `^[0-9\-\+]{9,15}$` match `-`, `+`  characters ? Up to 15 characters to be input ?

Comment: @guest271314 - fine.  how about this one?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386054/javascript-phone-number-validation

Comment: @devlincarnate That could be one approach. Though `javascript` is not necessary to meet requirement described at Question; see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern

Comment: @guest271314 - my point is that this question has been answered, in several ways, before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107772/discussion-between-guest271314-and-devlin-carnate).

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for this and it is called '[Jquery mask plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)'. Also there is another question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633726/phone-mask-with-jquery-and-masked-input-plugin). Check them out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pattern` attribute with `RegExp` `\d{10}` , `maxlength` set to `10`, `title` set to the message to be displayed to user at invalid submission , `placeholder` set to display message indicating expected format of input

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" 
         pattern="\d{10}" 
         maxlength="10" 
         placeholder="Input 10 digits"
         title="Input 10 digits" />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```