# validating length of the phone on click of submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mask

I want to  validate the length of the phone field on click of submit button
If the length of the phone field is less than 10 then it is supposed to give an error saying "this field should be 10 characters long". This is the HTML

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>

<input id="phone1" class="phone" placeholder="(___) ___-____"/>
<div class="error"></div>
<input id="phone2" class="phone" placeholder="(___) ___-____"/>
<div class="error"></div>
<input id="phone3" class="phone" placeholder="(___) ___-____"/>
<div class="error"></div>

<input style="float: right; margin-bottom:20px" type="submit" id="myBtn1" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"  />
```

this is what I tried to do so far, but it does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  
if(e.target) {
    let value = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g,'');
    if (value.length < 10) {
      $(e.target).next(".error").html('this field should be 10 characters long');
    } else {
      $(e.target).next(".error").html('');
    }
  }
});
```

I am new to jQuery. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to run that code when the form is being submitted, not in `document.ready()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery to validate phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840301/jquery-to-validate-phone-number)

Comment: I am masking the phone field so above solution wont work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue is that your code is currently running once when the document loads, rather than each time submit is clicked. Also, in the line `let value = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g,'');`, the `e.target` here is not any of the inputs.

Here is some updated code. I added a click event listener on the input, `$("#myBtn1").click(function(){...}`. Now when this submit input is clicked, we can trigger a function to run. This function will iterate on each input with `$(".phone").each(function(){...}` and validate their value. The `$(this)` selector refers to the current phone input field being validated.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myBtn1").click(function(){
    $(".phone").each(function(){
      let value = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g,'');
      if (value && value.length < 10) {
        $(this).next(".error").html('This field should be 10 characters long');
      } else {
        $(this).next(".error").html('');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="phone1" class="phone" placeholder="(___) ___-____"/>
<div class="error"></div>
<input id="phone2" class="phone" placeholder="(___) ___-____"/>
<div class="error"></div>
<input id="phone3" class="phone" placeholder="(___) ___-____"/>
<div class="error"></div>

<input style="float: right; margin-bottom:20px" type="submit" id="myBtn1" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"  />
```

Comment: Nick, None of the above fields are required. I am getting the error message even if I dont type anything in the phone field. I tried to modify your code like this: if (value.length < 10 && value !=""), but it doesn't work. can you modify the code so that it does not give error message when the field is empty

Comment: @rimi made the change by changing the condition to `if (value && value.length < 10)`. Yours didn't work because the initial value is actually `undefined`, not `""`